# Sharing global variables when shardtestfiles is set to true in

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor and i have a requirement where i need to read a value in one .spec file and provide it as input for another.

But i have shardTestfile set as 'true' as I need to open browser for each test.

I have tried using global variables in onprepare() method but it seems to be not working.

is there any way this can be achieved ?

Following is the code :

```
conf.js 

onPrepare: function() {
        console.log('on prepare');
       jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(getReporter());
        global.variable ='1';
    }

test1.spec:

 element(by.id('xyz')).getText().then(function(abc){
                 global.variable=abc;
               });
test2.spec:


    var xyz=global.variable;
    console.log('value is :' +xyz);

output :
value is 1
```

Comment: When you say that global variables are not working, what do you mean? Do you get any error? What kind of data would you want to share between test files? When you want this data to be shared, is it during test execution or before starting execution? Can you update your question with relevant code? Thanks

Comment: I have tried using the same but there is an error saying  the updated variable is not available for next test. The flow is some thing like this : I am reading a value of an element in one spec file                                 In test 1 file :             element(by.id('xyz')).getText().then(function(value){

                   global.searchthis= value;
               });                                            In test 2 file : element(by.id('placeTextHere')).sendKeys(global.searchthis);